# *Very Simple* Result of call to "== " is unused

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Have a UICollectionView implemented with multiple cells.

When you click on a cell I want to change the value in my selectedArray to true.

Here is my code:

```
var selectedArray = [Bool](count:201, repeatedValue:false)

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    if cell?.selected == true {
      selectedArray[indexPath.row] == true
      print("\(selectedArray[indexPath.row])")
  }
}
```

The output is false for every cell I click so I know something is not linked correctly but I just don't see it.

Comment: An NSMutableIndexSet is a more appropriate data structure to track selection.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to check to see if the cell is selected. Because you are calling `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, you do not need to check for this. Simply run this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedArray[indexPath.row] = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`selectedArray[indexPath.row] == true`  - need replace '==' to '='

Comment: hhmm I took out the if cell?.selected line and I am still getting the same results @Savchenko

Comment: @Cameron, strange.. What u doing also with selectedArray ?

Comment: nothing yet, I just have the two lines in my func : selectedArray[indexPath.row] == true and
print("\(selectedArray[indexPath.row])")

Comment: @Cameron, selectedArray[indexPath.row] **==** true, may be need replace '==' to '=' ?

Comment: double equal sign it compare, not setting

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Comment: @Cameron, Good! Don't forget to note my answer as correct ;D